# private key has strange format

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet

I created a paperwallet with myetherwallet a while ago. I tried to scan my private key with coinomi inorder to swipe the wallet, but I got an error: "There was a problem scanning: unsupported address"

my address looks as follows: (not an exact copy, but the + signs and the quanity of letters/digits are the same)

```
U2HGjk6Lhgf76hkl7KK890hgRRjkl097jjggujgf97khdhJ778Kw+pbH08jg7b8Ytt55G+hJhG755jkl8kkgFK55HJkkg8qrL54MGFkoFFDeK775JJL4333HHKKLPP99
```

The address looks strange to me, as I thought it should be 64 letters and numbers.
Is this an encrypted key? Is the key corrupt, or most likely do I have no clue what I'm doing???

Thanks for your help

Comment: That doesn't look like an address commonly used by ethereum, it looks like base 64, but can be anything. Are you sure that it was generated by MyEtherWallet?

Answer (score 1):

It has the same length as an encrypted private key. Have you an password?
Try it on the myetherwallet.com site

https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info

Check "Private Key"

Comment: please try to provide a better answer, or comment the question

Comment: I hope it solved the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you decrypt the key? ethaddress.org no longer exists.

Comment: Mike, did you try the myetherwallet.com site? https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same thing: Paper ETHereum wallet causes error when sweeping private key into Coinomi. However - scanning same QR and pasting into myetherwallet.com works just fine.  Here's a test. See for yourself. Please do NOT import the .$11 unless you absolutely need it to to fix this.

Ethereum paper wallet - generated by MyEtherWallet.com